# Identity 2.0 Reset password by Admin

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

How can I reset password as a admin for other users?

I have tried using the code below

```
var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, code, vm.NewPassword);
```

when stepping through GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync, the dispose method of the controller is called.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also extend UserManager and expose an explicit AdminChangePassword API that doesn't require any information.  Something like this in ApplicationUserManager which extends UserManager should work:

```
public IdentityResult ChangePasswordAdmin(string userId, string newPassword) {
     var user = FindById(userId);
     // validate password using PasswordValidator.Validate
     user.PasswordHash = PasswordHasher.HashPassword(newPassword);
     Update(user);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I should have searched more before posting question here.

Apparently I need to wire up UserTokenProvider with a DataProtectorTokenProvider.

However I do not understand what's a DataProtector for, would be glad if someone can explain here.

```
var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
{
    manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<MyUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
}
```

Answer is found [here](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2112)

Comment: what does `options` refer to?

Comment: `
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context){

var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<DBModel>()));

 var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider =
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<MyUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }

            return manager;
        }
`