# Migrating plain-text password to asp.net Identity 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I am moving an existing site to mvc and one of the thing that puzzles me is the migration of user data, particularly passwords, these passwords are stored as plain text (yes i know).  Now moving the rest of the account information to aspnet identity tables is easy but I need to now hash these passwords and I am not sure how to properly hash them before storage (using tsql), if i must use a .net app to hash, what class do i need to call by feeding it plain password and it will give me a hash?

thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783249/identity-2-0-reset-password-by-admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your application isn't set up right for a complete migration, so I have an idea for an easy solution to get the full use out of the Identity 2.0 database and features.

Create New Web Application, then create a method that gets the plain text login credientials for your old users. Next:

When you create a new application look at the code in the account/register files.

Here is what you see:

```
    var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text };
    IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {

    }
```

Now create a class to hold all the properties from your existing user, or you could use a `SQLDataReader["columnName"]` if you wanted to go the rout of looping a reader.

So copy that code run your new Method:

```
   var ListOfUsers = MyMethodThatRetunsAllOldMembers();
   foreach member in ListOfUsers{
    var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Member.UserName, Email = Member.Email };
    IdentityResult result = manager.Create(member.LoginName, Member.Password);


    //Example: You can even add roles at the same time.
    var ra = new RoleActions();
    ra.AddUserToRoll(member.LoginName, Member.Email, userRole);

    }
```

This will create the new hashed passwords as well as settings roles and userid's for each of your old users, effectively migrating your database.