# Change OWIN Identity password with out old password by code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a web application in MVC5 with OWIN Identity and i want to know if there is a posibility to change from code a user password with out knowing the old password. Because the method `ChangePassword` ask for `userId`, `oldPassword` and `newPassword`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In this case you will be treating ChangePassword as Reset Password. You can achieve this by using reset password by generating token and using that token straightaway to validate it with new password.

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(userId);

var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(userId, token, newPassword);
```

Check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783249/identity-2-0-reset-password-by-admin) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've seen the `UserManager` class in every example but how do i create this class?

Comment: UserManager class is located in namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity. I prefer creating a child class from this, for example: public class MyUserManager : UserManager<User, Guid> Where User is the entity that holds your user data