# MVC5 - Identity Authorization - Is it possible for me to change a password for one of my users?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've built an MVC 5 app using Identity authorization. I have reset password functionality in place, and it works fine, for 99% of the users. However, I have a very small percentage of users who forget their passwords and are either intimitdated by the reset process or just cannot seem to do it correctly.

Is it possible for me to reset a password on behalf of someone else? It doesn't appear possible to do this, but wanted to verify.

Comment: Maybe this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783249/identity-2-0-reset-password-by-admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change password directly yes you can do it.

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);

String hashedNewPassword = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword("password_you_want");
ApplicationUser cUser = await store.FindByIdAsync(AspNetUserId);
await store.SetPasswordHashAsync(cUser, hashedNewPassword);
await store.UpdateAsync(cUser);
```